# Keep jQuery file versions from conflicting with eachother

Tags: jquery

Out of all the pages on my sharepoint site, I have **1** page that requires using...

jQuery tools & videolightbox & jQuery 1.3.2 (all one package!).

The rest of the site is using jQuery 1.8.3

But on this same page, the header, menu and footer require the use of jQuery 1.8.3 in order to run properly.  This is where my conflict is occurring and where I am getting a headache.

**On this single/conflicting page, how can I prevent the jQuery 1.3.2 from conflicting with any of my other jQuery 1.8.3 methods and functions that are loaded in custom-scripts-for-the-whole-site.js file?**

Below is a demo of how my code is setup at the bottom of my master template...

```
   <!--THESE 2 FILES WORK GREAT FOR THE ENTIRE SITE-->
   <script src=".../jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src=".../custom-scripts-for-the-whole-site.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*THIS SECTION LOADS JQUERY 1.3.2 IN ORDER FOR JQUERY TOOLS AND VIDEOLIGHTBOX TO WORK
     JQUERY TOOLS BUNDLES 1.3.2 WITHIN IT'S OWN FILE! - FYI
     I SET UP A CONDITIONAL STATEMENT TO LOAD THIS CODE ONLY ON THIS SPECIFIC PAGE.
     */
    var mLof = document.getElementById("donate-landing-page");
    if(mLof !=null) {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.tools.min.live.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/swfobject.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/videolightbox.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.easing.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
    //*/
    </script>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `$.noConflict` <kbd>[API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)</kbd>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*THIS SECTION LOADS JQUERY 1.3.2 IN ORDER FOR JQUERY TOOLS AND VIDEOLIGHTBOX TO WORK
 JQUERY TOOLS BUNDLES 1.3.2 WITHIN IT'S OWN FILE! - FYI
 */
var mLof = document.getElementById("donate-landing-page");
if(mLof !=null) {
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.tools.min.live.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/swfobject.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/videolightbox.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/jquery.easing.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
jq132 = $.noConflict(true);
}
//*/
</script>
```